# Trying to locate science fiction story about virtual romance based on Weizenbaum's Eliza

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, virtual-worlds

I'm trying to identify a story that appeared in a magazine late 1960s early 1970s, in which the protagonist is having a romance (mediated by some form of electronic communication) with a woman. Despite frequent plans to meet it never happens, and the reader, but not the protagonist, realizes that the woman is not real. Years later I realized that the "woman" must have been modeled on [Weizenbaum's Eliza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA). Does this story seem familiar to anyone? I'm interested in people's desire to accept comforting illusions.